# How to make table visible, only after button click?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a table that shows content from a file. The content itself shows up when the button is clicked, but how do I hide the `th elements` until the button is pressed?

```
<span @onclick="() => editFile(Text)">
    <button>Edit</button>
</span>

 
<table >
    @foreach (var item in oneFile)
    {
        <input @bind="item.Title" type="text" />
    }    
    <thead >
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">Line</th>
        <th scope="col">One</th>
        <th scope="col">Two</th>
        <th scope="col">Three</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        @foreach (var item in items)
        {
                
            <tr>
                <td>@(items.IndexOf(item) + 1)</td>
                <td>
                    <input @bind="item.One" type="number" size="3" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input @bind="item.Two" type="number" size="3" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input @bind="item.Three" type="number" size="3" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is not to render them. You could have a flag and depending on the value of the flag you can display or hide components of your page.

```
<span @onclick="() => editFile(Text)">
    <button>Edit</button>
</span>

 

    <table >
        @foreach (var item in oneFile)
        {
            <input @bind="item.Title" type="text" />
        }    
        <thead >
            @if(isShown)
            {
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">Line</th>
                <th scope="col">One</th>
                <th scope="col">Two</th>
                <th scope="col">Three</th>
                </tr>
            }
        </thead>
        <tbody >
            @foreach (var item in items)
            {
                    
                <tr>
                    <td>@(items.IndexOf(item) + 1)</td>
                    <td>
                        <input @bind="item.One" type="number" size="3" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input @bind="item.Two" type="number" size="3" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input @bind="item.Three" type="number" size="3" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

@code
{
    bool isShown = false;

    void editFile(string Text)
    {
         isShown = true;
    }

}
```